# Java: nio WatchService - Can't detect second file creation. Why?

Tags: java, key, nio

i am trying to detect file creation in a folder but `WatchService` can't detect second file creation. it stucks at `key = watcher.take()`. Any idea why? I am using Ubuntu 11.04 x86.

```
private void watchWorkingDirectory() {
    try {
        WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        WatchKey key;
        key = Paths.get(tailSource, "").register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);

        for (;;) {

            System.err.println("Watching current working directory...............................................");
            // wait for key to be signalled
            key = watcher.take();

            System.out.println("Event detected:");


            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    tailSource = event.context().toString();
                    System.out.println(tailSource);
                    File file = new File(tailSource);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    tailer = new Tailer(file, tListener, 1, false);
                    (new Thread(tailer)).start();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I assume your application just sits at `take()`  Can log if you get any unexpected events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to invoke key.reset() after processing events.

http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes